Can Pandas GroupBy split into just 2 bins?
Imagine I have this table:
Col-1 | Col-2
A     |   2
A     |   3
B     |   1
B     |   4
C     |   7

Groupby on Col-1 with a sum aggregation on Col-2 will sum A to 5, B to 5, and C to 7.
What I want to know is if there is a baked in feature that allows aggregation on a target value in a column and then groups all other entries into another bin.  For example, if I wanted to groupby on Col-1 targeting A and grouping all other entries into a label named other, I would end up with A as 5 and Other as 12.
Does that make sense?  I know I could do some filtering sorcery and merging datasets back together, but figured there had to be a cleaner, more Pythonic way I am missing.
I have tried going through the documentation, but nothing jumped out at me.

One solution is to make pd.Categorical from the Column 1 -> with two categories A for string A and Other for other strings. Then group by this categorical:
tmp = pd.Categorical(df["Col1"], categories=["A", "Other"]).fillna("Other")

out = df.groupby(tmp, observed=False)["Col2"].sum()
print(out)

Prints:
A         5
Other    12
Name: Col2, dtype: int64


Another solution, group by boolean mask:
out = (
    df.groupby(df["Col1"].eq("A"))["Col2"]
    .sum()
    .rename(index={True: "A", False: "Other"})
)
print(out)

Prints:
Col1
Other    12
A         5
Name: Col2, dtype: int64


Nice and accurate answer. What about categories=["A", "Other"] when setting categories?

@PandaKim You're right, it can be simplified to tmp = pd.Categorical(df["Col1"], categories=["A", "Other"]).fillna("Other")
